# package.json not created using npm init

Tags: node.js, npm, init, package.json

on running npm init command inside the terminal the package.json file is not created inside the desired folder.
on running dir command it shows that the package.json file is created .
[Details on running dir command and npm init -y command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjp1C.png)

Comment: What's the problem? The `package.json` is presents in the correct folder.

Comment: I agree with @ema `package.json` is project wide so it's where it needs to be

Comment: The problem is that it shows that package.json file is present in the correct folder but on exploring the folder it is not present there @ema

Comment: What do you mean by "exploring the folder"? In your screenshot you ran the `dir` command, and `package.json` was listed.

Comment: I am using atom idea to write programs and inside it the file is not listed and also on opening the folder on the desktop which should contain the file, the file is not there.....

Comment: i am using atom ide**

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json file is present in the node-tests directory. Because node-tests was your current directory while running npm init command. If you want the package.json file to be created in another directory you first need to change the directory by using `cd <dir name>` command and then run `npm init`.

**OR** if node-tests is the desired directory and package.json file is not visible after it is initialized, then check **hidden items** and **file name extensions** as follows:
[image]